# CSV File with values having single quote within quote text qualifier

Tags: excel, csv, opencsv, univocity

I am trying to parse a CSV file which has single quote as text qualifier. The problem here is that some values with single quote text qualifier itself contains single quote
e-g:

```
'Fri, 24 Feb 2017 17:44:57 +0700','th01ham000tthxs','/','','Writer's Tools Data','7.1.0.0',
```

I am struggling to parse the file as after this row, all of the remaining rows get displaced.

I tried working with OpenCSV, UnivocityParsers but didn't get any luck.
If I place the above row in excel ([Excel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aaAn.png)) and provide text qualifier as single quote, it give correct result without any displacement of rows.

Comment: if you got it working in excel sounds like you found a solution

Comment: But I dont know how excel handles this. I was thinking to achieve something like that from OpenCSV or UnivocityParsers as perhaps these libraries handle such sort of scenerios

Answer (score 0):

If using java, the [JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/) library should handle the File.

**How it works:** if a field starts with a quote (e.g. **,'**) specifically look for **',** or **''',** or **''''',** or **'** etc (an **odd number of quotes** followed by either a **comma** or **end-of-line** marker). This approach breaks down if:

- The embedded quote is the last character in a field i.e.  **'Field with quote '',**
- White space between the quote and comma i.e. **'Field' ,** or **, '**

Here is the line in [ReCsvEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/recsveditor/)

[image: ReCsvEditor]

---

Also in the ReCsvEditor when editing the file, if you select **Generate >>> Java Code >>> ...** it will generate Java/JRecord Code to read the file.

[image: ReCsvEditor Generate]

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of JRecord / ReCvEditor. Also the ReCsvEditor Generate function is new and needs more work

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring univocity-parsers to handle the unescaped quote according to your scenario. `'Writer's Tools Data'` has an unescaped quote. From your input, I can see you want to use `STOP_AT_CLOSING_QUOTE` as the strategy to work around these values.

Add this line to your code and it should work fine:

```
parserSettings.setUnescapedQuoteHandling(UnescapedQuoteHandling.STOP_AT_CLOSING_QUOTE);
```

Hope this helps.